# How do I combine two simple curves, to make them either averaged or one limits the amplitude of the other?

Tags: curves

This looks like it should be really simple, but unfortunately I'm not quickly understanding the basic lessons I've looked over. I have two simple sine curves here, with periods $p_1$ and $p_2$ (I'm prepared to be wrong on my terminology and notation):
$$ 
x = \cos ( x \cdot p_1 ) \qquad x = \sin ( x \cdot p_2 ) \\
p_1 = 94.247 \qquad p_2 = 1.5707\\
0 \le x \le 1 \quad -1 \le y \le 1
$$
I'm trying to combine them such that the resulting curve's amplitude is limited near $0$ at the start and has gradually increasing amplitude until it reaches $1$. The second curve is just an unimportant guiding behavior and seems final, but I'll still be adjusting the period of the first curve $(p_1)$ for more changes. (I don't know how I was supposed to arrive at the period multipliers, but that's not important, the trial-and-error values work fine)

I've been working with curve editors for years, being mindful of the trigonometry behind it. But I haven't had use for the equations in 12 years, I couldn't even remember how to graph and adjust a sine wave. I'm sorry if it looks a bit negligent asking for answers on something basic, but I've spent 12 total hours across 2 days getting this far, on what I was only supposed to spend 2 hours on. I did at least figure out getting values I need by working with $x = \frac{ 2 \pi \arccos ( y )} p $

Have a good day!

Appended sketch: [https://i.imgur.com/7bJqpH7.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKPKj.jpg)

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're asking. Can you add a sketch of your desired result?

Comment: Okay! The resulting curve I'm hoping for is this: https://i.imgur.com/7bJqpH7.jpg (while still hoping to adjust the smaller frequency, but I still want this 0 to 1 easing)

Comment: Oh, then you can just multiply them: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+cos(94.2x),+sin(1.57x),+cos(94.2x)sin(1.57x)+for+x%3D0..1

Comment: Interesting! Thank you! I did think that would be the case, but I guess I messed something up when I was trying. In fact trying it just now I shuffled solving for x instead of y. Oh my. Thanks for helping!  (I don't know etiquette here, if it's proper to still add an Answer post, I'll mark it as good; otherwise thanks for making my day better!)